# I'm getting a blank Crystal Report after query

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am creating a report dynamically using the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim mycon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" + My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\mswd-rms.mdb")
        Dim mycomm As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_day_care", mycon)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter()
        da.SelectCommand = mycomm
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl_day_care")

        Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1() 'The report you created. 

        rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
        frmViewReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        frmViewReport.Show()
    End Sub
```

But when the report loads, the report is blank. The table where I am getting the records from is not empty.

Comment: Did you try debug this code. What's the row count on 'ds'

Comment: How do I get the row count?

Comment: Ds.rowcount or Ds.row Is this code in vb6 or vb.net?

Comment: vb.net, rowcount and row is not a method of dataset

Comment: there are seven records. I used ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count

Comment: Pl update tag it's say vb6. Check ds have any row when u r debug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23463/discussion-between-hiten004-and-jayson-tamayo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just follow this steps, hope it helps :)

Link: http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_step_by_step.htm

Comment: how do i show an input box to the user and use the value to display specific record in the report?